# Moving specific files to specific folders

Tags: powershell

I have a list of XML file names (including the full path to the file) in a .txt document:

```
C:\Files\www_site1_com\order\placed\test45.xml
C:\Files\www_site1_com\order\placed\test685.xml
C:\Files\www_site2_com\order\placed\test63.xml
C:\Files\www_site3_com\order\placed\test9965.xml
C:\Files\www_site4_com\order\placed\test4551.xml
etc...
```

The idea is that I need to move the XML files to a different folder, so for example:

```
C:\Files\www_site1_com\order\placed\test45.xml
    will be moved to
C:\Files\www_site1_com\order\in\test45.xml

C:\Files\www_site1_com\order\placed\test685.xml
   will be moved to
C:\Files\www_site1_com\order\in\test685.xml
```

The problem is I am not sure how I can go about to actually move each file into the destination folder it is supposed to go into.

Below is the portion of my script that deals with the move.
This first portion takes the list of the XML files, and replaces \placed\ to \in\ , so that I end up with the destination:

```
$content =  Get-Content dump.txt    
ForEach ($path in $content)
{
$path = $content -Split "\\t"
$paths = $path -notlike "*t*"
$paths = $paths -Replace ("placed","in")
}
```

Which ends up giving me:

```
C:\Files\www_site1_com\order\in
C:\Files\www_site1_com\order\in
C:\Files\www_site2_com\order\in
C:\Files\www_site3_com\order\in
C:\Files\www_site4_com\order\in
```

Next, to move the files I am trying:

```
ForEach ($path in $paths)
{
Move-Item -Path $path -Destination $paths
}
```

But i am ending up with all kind of errors:

```
Move-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Destination'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:3 char:36
+ Move-Item -Path $path -Destination $paths  -WhatIf
+                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

I've tried with a few variations but have only managed to get ALL the files moved into the first destination folder and not into the correct ones. 
I hope I've explained this well enough! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$path = $content -Split "\\t"
```

produces an array of strings (and $paths ends up being an array of strings as well). The `-Destination` arguments will not accept an array. It also doesn't seem very robust (what if one of your directories starts with a t?)

Instead use Split-Path:

```
$sourceDirectories = $content | Split-Plath -Parent
```

You can then replace the leaf of these directories by hiving off the parent and appending your desired target directory:

```
$destDirectories =  $sourceDirectories | Split-Path -Parent | Join-Path -ChildPath "in"
```

then you can move them, but I would do it all in a single loop:

```
$content | foreach {
    $sourceDirectory = Split-Plath $_ -Parent
    $destDirectory = Split-Path $sourceDirectory -Parent | Join-Path -ChildPath "in"
    Move-Item $_ $destDirectory
}
```

Comment: Awesome zdan, Thanks for the tip about the info on the array. I gave this a quick test and seems to be doing exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to actually edit the text file contents, as `move-item` doesn't create folders for you. If you were using `copy-item` it could create the folders as needed then something like that might work better. However try something like this:

```
$content =  Get-Content dump.txt

#If you want to explicitly create a particular directory
#New-Item -Name "in" -type directory

foreach($item in $content){
    $fileCheck = Test-Path $item

    if($fileCheck){
        try{
            Move-Item -LiteralPath $item -Destination "C:\Files\www_site1_com\order\in\" -PassThru
        }
        catch{
            write-error $_
        }
    }
    else{
        write-warning "$item was not found"
    }
}
```